# Microsoft Team Members are not in the associated SharePoint site Members group

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, microsoft-teams

**Context**

I created a Microsoft Team which created an associated SharePoint site.

I created a SharePoint List on the site and have granted the default `Members` group a custom permission level on it.

The custom permission level is nothing fancy, it is just designed to let users add items, but not delete or edit them.

I believe, by default, Microsoft Team members are added to both the `Visitors` and `Members` groups.

**Desired Behaviour**

Users who are members of the Microsoft Team are also in the `Members` SharePoint group and therefore can be granted custom permissions on lists etc.

**Actual Behaviour**

Users only have Read access on the list, which is the permission level that users in the `Visitors` group have.

Microsoft Team members do not seem to be in the `Members` group and therefore do not have the custom permission level applied.

I *think* I may have caused this behaviour by clicking on the Settings cog in the top right of the site and changing the `Members` group permissions in the `Site members` section:

[image]

[image]

If that is the case, how do I get the Microsoft Team members back in the `Members` group?

**PS**

I am confused because the site still lists the Microsoft Teams Member count:

[image]

Related Screenshots

`....sharepoint.com/sites/group-name/_layouts/15/groups.aspx` page:

[image]

`....sharepoint.com/sites/group-name/_layouts/15/user.aspx` page:

[image]

Clicking on the default `Owners/Members/Visitors` links does not list any users, however when i click on the `Members` group and then `New` and `Shared With` - the `Owner` and `Member` groups seem to be listed, eg:

[image]

[image]

Checking permissions for a Microsoft team member:

[image]

Related Reading:

https://sharegate.com/blog/how-broken-are-office-365-sharepoint-permissions

Answer (score 0):

By default, the M365 Group Members are in the SharePoint Online 'Members' SharePoint group. Looks like someone altered the permission level of the M365 Group from Edit to Read (or used the classic SharePoint UI).

You just need to change the Members group permission from Read to Edit.

Comment: `.../_layouts/15/user.aspx` has three items, as shown in the image in OP.  The `Members` item already has `Edit` permission level.

Answer (score 0):

The site members section always displays the members in the SharePoint group "Site Name members".

By default when the team site created automatically by M365, the M365 group members shall be added to the SP group. It could be later changes which removes the members from the SharePoint group, which makes you cannot find them in the site permissions> members section.

Just add the members back to the site members group, you can find them in the site permission section. It is not a issue with permission level, but the group.