# Microsoft Team Members are not added in SharePoint Members group automatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, restore, microsoft-teams

I have a similar issue with the one describe here, but couldn't see any solution. [Microsoft Team Members are not in the associated SharePoint site Members group](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/286574/microsoft-team-members-are-not-in-the-associated-sharepoint-site-members-group)

**Issue:**
When I add a member in Teams group, he appears as a member in the associated SharePoint site but it is not added to the default "Members group". So he cannot see any folder in SharePoint as he has not rights to do anything.
[image]

**Question:**
Long story short, I believe the "Members group was deleted" by accident, and now I need to restore it. The members group to be restored should look like this (as default)
[image]
I'm looking all over the internet, and can't seem to find a solution. Anyone out there who is a genius, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just some information about SharePoint and MS Team Permission architecture - By default SharePoint team site is part of a Microsoft 365 group. a Microsoft 365 group is a single permissions group that is associated with various Microsoft 365 services. This includes a SharePoint site, an instance of Planner, a mailbox, a shared calendar, and others.

When we add owners or members to the Microsoft 365 group, they're given access to the SharePoint site along with the other group-connected services. Group owners become site owners, and group members become site members.

So here MS Teams owner becomes a member of SharePoint site Owner permission Group and MS team Members becomes Member of Site member permission group.

**As per the actual question** - if MS Team members is deleted accidentally then just by assigning permission to MS Teams Members to Site member permission group will restore the permission. it just by searching '"MSTeams Name" Members'

Hope this answered your question. Please let me know if you need more information.